# Verification Proof of Discontinuity of Sine Function at x=0

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Show that the following function is not continuous at $0$.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0, & \text{when $x=0$} \\ \sin\left(\frac{1}{2x}\right), & \text {when $x\neq0$}  \end{cases}$$

## Proof.

To prove discontinuity we need to analyze the One-Sided Limits of the function.

### To prove that the right limit does not exist,

let consider the sequence $\{x_n\} = \frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}$,

and observe that $\sin (\frac{1}{2x})$ = $(-1)^n$.

Since {$x_n$} converges to 0 but $(-1)^n$ does not converge,

it follows from the Sequential Characterization of Continuity Theorem

that the right limit does not exist.

### To prove that the left limit does not exist,

let consider the sequence $\{x_n\} = \frac{-1}{(2n+1)\pi}$,

and observe that $\sin \left(\frac{1}{2x}\right) = (-1)^{n+1}$.

Since $\{x_n\}$ converges to $0$ but $(-1)^{n+1}$ does not converge,

it follows from the Sequential Characterization of Continuity Theorem that the left limit does not exist.

## Therefore, $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$. Q.E.D.

Comment: This is indeed a correct argumentation. Although actually showing that one of the one-sided limits is non zero would have been sufficient.

Comment: Great proof!  As is mentioned in the comment above, once you show the right limit doesn't exist, you can stop there.  No matter what result you get for the left limit, the left limit can't equal the right limit since the right limit doesn't exist, and hence the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: perfect. nothing to add.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, an equivalent characterization of continuity of a function $f$ at $x$ is that for every sequence $x_{n}$ such that $x_{n} \to x$, we get $f(x_{n}) \to f(x)$.  So you could have started the proof saying "we will exhibit a sequence which converges to $x=0$, but for which the sequence of images doesn't converge to $f(0)=0$", and then your argument for the left limit would work perfectly.

Comment: @b00nheT Thank you for your comment. I used both limits because there is a definition of continuity that requires only right side or left side limit, but not both.

Comment: @Beginner That's usually referred to as *right continuous* (if only the right limit must exist) or *left continuous* (if only the left limit must exist).

Comment: @user46944 I appreciate your insight.  I used both limits because there is a definition of continuity that requires only right side or left side limit, but not both.

Comment: @danuznanski Thank you so much for editing my question. May you fix the symbols that are missing the sequence in the left limit?

Comment: @46944 Thank you for the clarification about right continuous and left continuous! I did not know those terms.

Comment: @danuznanski Sorry to ask for help again. I discovered that for the left limit instead of (-1)^n should be (-1)^(n+1). May you change it, please?

Comment: Get ye to the tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way overwritten.  Here is a shorter proof.

There exists a sequence $x_{n}$ of positive numbers that converges to $0$ and such that the sequence $\sin(1 / x_{n}) = (-1)^n$ fails to converge.  Thus, function $f(x)$ fails to be right-continuous at $0$.  Since function $\sin(x)$ is odd, the sequence $-x_{n}$ analogously shows failure of left-continuity at $0$ for $f(x)$.

Comment: I think you're expecting too much from a beginner.  OP will work their way to writing shorter proofs as they continue to learn.  For their current level, their proof is fine.

Comment: You are probably right.  Just wanted to guard them against the Bourbakist habit of over-formalizing everything, so prevalent in modern mathematics.

Comment: @user8960 Thank you so much for your ideas. I love short proofs! I just did not see a way to do it.

Comment: @user890 However, you did not write which sequence. Would that be correct?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be.  But I left it out of the main proof on purpose and suggest including it as a footnote, because the choice of the specific sequence doesn't matter, as long as it makes $f(x_{n})$ fail to converge.

Comment: In other proofs, a specific sequence may play a key role (e.g., no other sequence will do).  Then it should be part of the main proof.

Comment: @user8960 Thank you! Very interesting!

Comment: Here's an even shorter proof ;). Since $f(x) = 1$ and $-1$ in every neighbourhood of $0$, $\omega_f(0) = 2 \neq 0$, QED

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, besides being short, a proof must also be self-sufficient, free of notation that may be present in your textbook, but not necessarily in others.:)  



But, even the appropriate edit of your proof makes it shorter than mine:

Since in every neighborhood of $0$ the function $f(x)$ attains each of the values $1, -1$, it cannot be continuous at $0$.